# Users in Active Directory not listed alphabetically?

Tags: active-directory

At one of my clients, I just created a new room mailbox for them to use. So, they had a room called Meeting Room. I renamed it to be Meeting Room 1, and created a new room, Meeting Room 2.

The customer is complaining that in the GAL, Meeting Room 2 comes before Room 1 (alphabetically) and looking at active directory (at the list of users) confirms that for some reason, Room 2 is coming before room 1 alphabetically.

Is there any reason for this that you guys know of?

Server is running Windows SBS 2011. Please let me know if you need any more information.

Thanks!!

Comment: Extra space character in the name of Room 2? Before the "M" or before the "2"?  Also check all the name fields: Display, Full, First, Last, etc...

Comment: To remove that possibility, I copy/pasted the name of room 1, and just changed it to a 2. Still not alphabetically correct. Very strange